# IndexOutOfRange exception when giving values to a jagged array

Tags: c#, arrays, jagged-arrays, leap-motion, indexoutofrangeexception

I'm trying to compare a sensor value with the values saved in a jagged array (26 saved possible cases, 5 fingers, 3d vector for each finger)
When I'm defining the values for the array, I can set the value of gestures[0] without any problems, but as soon as I start defining gestures[1],
I get an IndexOutOfRange exception.

Also, are jagged arrays good for this purpose (array of arrays of 3d vectors)?

```
public class Signs
{
public static double[][][] gestures = new double[26][][];

    public void Define()
    {


        gestures[0] = new double[5][];
        gestures[0][0] = new double[3] { 0.15, 0.97, -0.21 };
        gestures[0][1] = new double[3] { -0.56, -0.81, -0.18 };
        //...
        gestures[0][5] = new double[3] {-0.21,0.44,0.2}



        gestures[1] = new double[5][]; //IndexOutOfRange exception
        gestures[1][0] = new double[3] { 0.21, 0.96, -0.21 };
        gestures[1][1] = new double[3] { 0.19, 0.96, 0.21 };
        //...
```

Comment: I would say that the Index Out Of Range is thrown in the line _gestures[0][5] = new double[3] {-0.21,0.44,0.2}_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this line

```
gestures[0][5] = new double[3] {-0.21,0.44,0.2}
```

You defined an array with length 5 (`gestures[0] = new double[5][];`)

So max index is 4 (0-4)

Comment: That solved it, the compiler was throwing the exception at the following line, so that was what confused me.